# Копирование формата сообщения пользователя telebot

Tags: python, telebot, формат

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы каким-то образом сохранить формат сообщения (жирный, курсив, подчёркнутый текст и т.д.) пользователя, после чего отправить ему точную копию его сообщения с тем же форматом. Как это можно сделать?

UPD: Такой код почему-то не работает, бот отправляет обычное сообщение, без формата:

```
def copy_format(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=message.text, entities=message.entities)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Отправь сообщение с форматом')
    bot.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(chat_id=message.chat.id, callback=copy_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить

```
def copy_format(message):
    text2 = update.message.reply_text
    bot.update.message.reply_text(message.chat.id, caption=text2, entities=message.entities, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

Comment: Поправил чутка код

Comment: А откуда взялась переменная update?

Comment: Если заменить update.message.reply_text на message.reply_text я получу сообщение о том, что в message  нет атрибута reply_text

Answer (score 0):

Есть только один способ (или я не нашел других):

При вводе формата пользователем, он должен ввести не как обычно `__text__`, а `_text_`. Или не `**text**`, а `*text*` и в таком случае Вам необходимо добавить в строку `parse_mode` `=` `Markdown`:

```
def copy_format(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=message.text, entities=message.entities, parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Что мы получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл способ. У объекта сообщения (Message) есть метод html_text. Не уверен насчёт markdown_text, но работает это следующим образом:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def handler(msg):
    formatted_text = msg.html_text
    print(html_text)
```